# When the batteries are fully discharged, the lens does not get in!

Tags: lens, battery, sony

I own Sony HX 300 camera. I have two batteries. In one particular lithium battery, the camera cannot get its lens in when the batteries are fully discharged. On the other hand, the other battery has enough power (even after getting fully discharged) to keep its lens back into the place.

> Is the battery at fault? I'm not sure because it gives equal performance

Or I can do something for this? Because the lens remains out and then I need to put another battery (charged one) to get it back into the place but imagine that I don't have another battery at times!

Comment: is one a genuine sony and the other a compatible battery?

Comment: @DarkcatStudios It's genuine Sony Battery (and thus it gives the same performance as the original one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all my compact cameras I ever owned (starting from the original Digital IXUS), when the battery was completely empty (in the eyes of the camera) it would automatically switch off and retract the lens.

As this surely works by measuring the voltage of the battery, it seems that your one LiIon battery has a rather high voltage ar rest (no current flowing) while not being able to provide power. I consider this a defect of the battery and I would replace it.

The effect itself, battery seems to be able to provide power, but voltage completely brakes down when load is applied, is well known for worn-out batteries.